# Toggle "show password" when choosinig password for disk encryption

Tags: system-installation

I hope i'm not repeating a old question, or something already covered, but here goes!
For critical passwords like this, i very much like multi word passwords. So when doing long passswords like word.secondword.etc. I like having the option of checking if i'm putting in my password (that i then manage with a password manager) correctly.

Perhaps i was only being blind and didn't see a logo or something, but in that case i hope the logo or toggle becomes bigger in the release.

Really, really loving the beta so far though, cleanest OS experience ive ever had i think.

Comment: Thank you for your good thoughts, but this is not the right place to post suggestions for improvements. Go to elementary OS github and open an issue there describing how (and what) should change in the future. https://github.com/elementary/installer

Comment: Thank you ! For some reason i was scared of creating an "issue" on github, didn't want to create too much work for the devs. But I will do it!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! GIthub is the best spot for these things, since all devs can see them there, and discussions and code samples are easy to track there.

Comment: I've created an issue here. I feel this is a small but important detail. Hopefully it is easy to implement. 
https://github.com/elementary/installer/issues/570